# NSInternalInconsistencyException when running background fetch with a loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit, hksamplequery

I have this code that is trying to do a background fetch for HealthKit data.  The code works fine when I first run the app, but if I manually perform a background fetch (using the debug command), I get an exception thrown and an error that says `reason: 'this request has been neutered - you can't call -sendResponse: twice nor after encoding it'` and I'm not quite sure why.

Here is the code that fetches the data:

```
- (void)fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    if (!self.healthStore) {
        self.healthStore = [HKHealthStore new];
    }

    dataTypes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount,
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], HKQuantityTypeIdentifierFlightsClimbed,
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning,
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceCycling, nil];
    achievementData = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *startDate = [calendar startOfDayForDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:1 toDate:startDate options:0];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate options:HKQueryOptionNone];

    for (NSString *key in dataTypes) {

        HKSampleType *sampleType = [HKSampleType quantityTypeForIdentifier:key];

        HKSampleQuery *query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:sampleType predicate:predicate limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit sortDescriptors:nil resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

            if (!error) {

                if (!results) {

                    NSLog(@"No results were returned form query");

                    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);

                } else {

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        [self processNewDataWithResults:results andType:key];

                        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

                    });

                }

            } else {

                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);

            }

        }];

        [self.healthStore executeQuery:query];

    }

}
```

Then I have a separate function that processes the data that you can see gets called when results are found.  If you want I can paste it in here but it is pretty lengthy, not sure if it has anything to do with it.

I have tried putting breakpoints in to see when the completion handler is called but from what I can tell it is only getting called once, unless I am missing something silly here.

If anyone has any advice, please let me know :) Thanks!

**EDIT**
Here is what the error message looks like:

```
2015-05-13 10:11:54.467 appName[379:169163] *** Assertion failure in -[UIFetchContentInBackgroundAction sendResponse:], /SourceCache/BaseBoard/BaseBoard-98.3/BaseBoard/BSAction.m:221
2015-05-13 10:11:54.470 appName[379:169163] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'this request has been neutered - you can't call -sendResponse: twice nor after encoding it'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x28ed4137 0x36e30c77 0x28ed400d 0x29bd2bc9 0x2dbde865 0x397ed5 0x2dbde7cf 0x2ca82a3d 0x39019b 0x390187 0x393e9d 0x28e99889 0x28e97fa9 0x28de39a1 0x28de37b3 0x305951a9 0x2c56e695 0xdff29 0x373d8aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From looking at the code you posted, I do not see any other way than that the background fetch completion handler will be called exactly 4 times due to the `for` loop.

The code paths in the `resultHandlers` of each instance of `HKSampleQuery` will end up at a `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult...)` call in any case and you are always instantiating four of them, so this is what the assertion `'you can't call -sendResponse: twice'` is complaining about IMO.

It should be easy to check if that is the problem by commenting out 3 of the queries from the `dataTypes` dictionary.

**Edit:** as requested in the comments, here's a possible solution (..just off the top of my head, so take it with a grain of salt..):

It (a) uses a semaphore lock to turn the asynchronous query result callback into a "synchronous" call & (b) uses a dispatch group to wait for all 4 queries to finish before executing the completion handler.

```
// NOTE: This example assumes that the fetch has "new data" if any of the queries returned something
//       Also it skips the 'NSError' part (which could work exactly like the 'result' var)

// Define one or more block-global result variables for queries can put their end state into
UIBackgroundFetchResult __block result = UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData;

// Create a dispatch group that will manage all the concurrent queries
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create([@"my.query.queue" UTF8String], DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_group_t queries = dispatch_group_create();

// For each dataType dispatch a group block containing the query to run on the concurrent queue
for (NSString *key in dataTypes) {
    dispatch_group_async(queries, queue, ^{
        // To work around the asynchronous callback, I'll use a lock to wait for the query to return their result, so..

        // ..like above, a block-global var will hold the result of the query
        BOOL __block success = NO;

        // ..create a one-time lock..
        dispatch_semaphore_t lock = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        HKSampleQuery *query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:sampleType predicate:predicate limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit sortDescriptors:nil resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
            success = YES; // ..or however you define success.. ;)

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(lock);    // ..open lock to signal result available..
        }];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(lock, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);   // ..wait for callback result lock to open..

        // ..determine & set result.
        if (success) {
            result = UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData;
        }
    });
}

// Schedule a final block to execute (on the main queue) when all the other group blocks have finished running
dispatch_group_notify(queries, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Determine final result and call completion handler
    completionHandler(result);
});
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way where I can take the completion handler out of the loop, or maybe fetch the data differently? Thanks!

Comment: Basically you need a way to run the queries, get their respective results and call the completion handler once after *all* the results are back. There are several ways to do that, for instance using NSOperationQueues, or GCD. I'll amend the answer with some code based on dispatch groups that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is great stuff, I haven't messed around too much with GCD except for what I've found for tutorial on Healthkit queries.  I will give this a shot, I'll have to do more research on GCD and how that all comes in to play to learn more about it.  Thanks again!

Comment: This worked, thank you so much, I am no longer getting an error.